# div container fill width

Tags: html, css

I have an div container namend "content". This container got a width of 500px;.
Inside this div are two other divs. One div is called "right", with fixed width of 300px;. The other container ("left") should fill the rest width. Now I can give him a width of 200px, but when I resize the window the width does not change of the "left" container. I want that only the width of the second container "left" change, maybe with a % width?

[image]

And when I resize the window it should look like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.content{
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.left{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right{
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.clearBoth{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
  
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XD8s/295/)

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of `.content` to 100%? The width of the left must be a percentage if you want it to change during resizing. You say that  you "only [want] the width of the second container [to the] "left" [to] change", but in your illustration the right container becomes smaller.

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ - it will provide you the functionality you need withotu worying about percentages

Comment: @noa-dev yeha I was thinking about flexboxes too. But how can I do it then? I gave the first container the fixed width and I gave the second container the propertie `flex-grow : 1;`, but nothing happen.

Comment: Confusing! In your question, you say only the width of left container shall change but in your illustration widths of both containers are changing.

Answer (score 2):

You should Change Left Width size To 60%

```
.left{float: left;width: 60%;height: 20px;background-color: blue;}

.right{float: right; width: 40%;height: 20px; background-color: red;}
```

Comment: Only the width of the second container should change on resize ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this ? You have to resize the window to see the change.

I use `calc()` function in CSS :

```
.right{
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 310px);
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I also use a fluid width for the main container.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XD8s/301/)

Answer (score 0):

I think, this will be the best answer for you. please check the given below code snippet.

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.content{
  width: 100%;
  
}

.left{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right{
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);width: -webkit-calc(100% - 300px);width: -moz-calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.clearBoth{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
  
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7XD8s/300/

```
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of `calc`
http://jsfiddle.net/7XD8s/303/

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.left{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.clearBoth{
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will keep the width of right container fixed at 300px. Left container will occupy rest of the space with 10px margin on its right side.
Please note, total width of content container is 500px.

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.left{
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 310px);
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right{
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.clearBoth{
  clear: both;
}
```